# What's the difference between write, print, pprint, princ, and prin1?

Tags: printing, output, lisp, common-lisp

I'm getting into some Lisp, and I've come across various different functions that to me appear to be doing the same thing... Namely printing to console... So what exactly is the difference between all those different functions?

Comment: In general, [the HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/), to which Rainer Joswig's answer links is a very good reference for Common Lisp.  There's also a documentation search, [lispdoc](http://lispdoc.com/), that's very useful, as it searches the HyperSpec and some other Common Lisp language references.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is answered here: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm

- `write` is the general entry point to the Lisp printer.
- `prin1` produces output suitable for input to `read`.
- `princ` is just like `prin1` except that the output has no escape characters. `princ` is intended to look good to people, while output from `prin1` is intended to be acceptable for the function `read`.
- `print` is just like `prin1` except that the printed representation of object is preceded by a newline and followed by a space.
- `pprint` produces pretty output.

Comment: Is there a specification of what is "pretty" output? Indentation is one thing that I can think of. Might different implementations define it differently?

Comment: 'pretty printed' means layouted for the available horizontal space and indented accordingly.